# Convert a JWPlayer 5 script into a JWPlayer 6 script

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Someone can help me to convert this JWPlayer 5 code into a JWPlayer 6 code??
This script essentially creates an RTMP streaming for desktops and an HLS streaming for no-flash devices.
If the streaming source is not available, an .mp4 file will be played. After the end of the mp4 file, the script reloads the page to check if the streaming is returned as available. In case of negative response the script will repeat the steps before.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeout = null;
    jwplayer(document.getElementById("JWPLAYER_1080")).setup({
        'flashplayer': 'http://xxxxxx.embed.scaleengine.net/latest/jwplayer.swf',
        'autostart': 'true',
        'provider': 'rtmp',
        'streamer': 'rtmp://xxxxxx.videocdn.scaleengine.net/xxxxxx-live/play/',
        'file': 'xxxxxx.stream',
        'modes': [
        {
            'type': 'flash',
            'src': 'http://xxxxxx.embed.scaleengine.net/latest/jwplayer.swf'
        },
        {
            'type': 'html5',
            'config': {
                'file': 'http://xxxxxx.videocdn.scaleengine.net/xxxxxxxxx/play/xxxxxxxx.stream/playlist.m3u8',
                'provider': 'video'
            }
        }],
        'bufferlength': '5',
        'width': '720',
        'height': '405',
        events:{
            onBuffer: function(){
                if(timeout == null) {
                    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        var time = new Date();
        var currentTimeMillis = time.getTime();
        jwplayer().load({'file':"http://xxxxxx.tv/style/video/streaming.mp4?" + currentTimeMillis});
                    },5000);
                }
            },
            onPlay: function() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = null;
            },
            onComplete: function() {
                window.location="http://www.xxxxxx.net/streaming.php?quality=1080";
            },
            onIdle: function() {
                jwplayer().play();
            },
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try doing this yourself, or are you just asking for someone else to do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, I couldn't really test it because everything is a placeholder though. I did put some of my own files in there to test and it seemed to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/10/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="JWPLAYER_1080"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timeout = null;
        jwplayer(document.getElementById("JWPLAYER_1080")).setup({
            'autostart': 'true',
            playlist: [{
            sources: [{
            'file': 'rtmp://xxxxxx.videocdn.scaleengine.net/xxxxxx-live/play/xxxxxx.stream'
            },{
            'file': 'http://xxxxxx.videocdn.scaleengine.net/xxxxxxxxx/play/xxxxxxxx.stream/playlist.m3u8'
            }]
            }],
            rtmp: {
            'bufferlength': '5'
            },
            'width': '720',
            'height': '405',
            events:{
                onBuffer: function(){
                    if(timeout == null) {
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            var time = new Date();
            var currentTimeMillis = time.getTime();
            jwplayer().load({'file':"http://xxxxxx.tv/style/video/streaming.mp4?" + currentTimeMillis});
                        },5000);
                    }
                },
                onPlay: function() {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeout = null;
                },
                onComplete: function() {
                    window.location="http://www.xxxxxx.net/streaming.php?quality=1080";
                },
                onIdle: function() {
                    jwplayer().play();
                },
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```